# Apache Flink S3 file system credentials does not work

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink

I am trying to read csv file from Amazon S3 and I need to set credential info at runtime.
But I cant pass the credentials checking.
Is there any alternative or any suggestion?

```
object AwsS3CSVTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new Configuration();
    conf.setString("fs.s3a.access.key", "***")
    conf.setString("fs.s3a.secret.key", "***")
    val env = ExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(conf)
    val datafile = env.readCsvFile("s3a://anybucket/anyfile.csv")
      .ignoreFirstLine()
      .fieldDelimiter(";")
      .types(classOf[String], classOf[String], classOf[String], classOf[String], classOf[String], classOf[String])
    datafile.print()
  }
}
```

```
00:49:55.558|DEBUG|     o.a.h.f.s.AWSCredentialProviderList No credentials from TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.NoAwsCredentialsException: Session credentials in Hadoop configuration: No AWS Credentials
00:49:55.558|DEBUG|     o.a.h.f.s.AWSCredentialProviderList No credentials from SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.NoAwsCredentialsException: SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider: No AWS credentials in the Hadoop configuration
00:49:55.558|DEBUG|     o.a.h.f.s.AWSCredentialProviderList No credentials provided by EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained on https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/filesystems/s3/#configure-access-credentials you should use IAM or Access Keys which you configure in `flink-conf.yaml`. You can't set the credentials in code, because the S3 plugins are loaded via plugins.

Comment: Yes, I read that document. But i know that, Spark can do this via accessing hadoop configuration in runtime. We can change properties with 'sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key","***")'. I think this is really important while accessing different sources.

Comment: I agree that it's important, but it's currently not possible. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-19589 for the relevant ticket